# Extrapolating a whole curve with quadratic fit in R

Tags: r

I have four measurements of variable *y* along axis *x* at 4 *Temperature*s:

```
require(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 10, by = 0.1)
y1 <- cos(x)
y2 <- cos(x) + 0.2
y3 <- cos(x) + 0.4
y4 <- cos(x) + 0.8

df.1 <- data.frame(x, y = y1, Name = "df.1", Temperature = 4)
df.2 <- data.frame(x, y = y2, Name = "df.2", Temperature = 3)
df.3 <- data.frame(x, y = y3, Name = "df.3", Temperature = 2)
df.4 <- data.frame(x, y = y4, Name = "df.4", Temperature = 1)

df.merged <- rbind(df.1, df.2, df.3, df.4)

ggplot(df.merged, aes(x, y, color = Name)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

All curves have the same x values. What I want is to use a quadratic fit and derive a 5th curve, extrapolated to Temperature = 0.

What I did is the following:

```
require(splines)
quadratic.model <- with(df.merged,
                        lm(y ~ bs(Temperature, degree = 2)))

result <- predict.lm(quadratic.model, data.frame(x, Temperature = 0))
df.5 <- data.frame(x, y = result, Name = "df.5", Temperature = 0)
df.merged <- rbind(df.1, df.2, df.3, df.4, df.5)
ggplot(df.merged, aes(x, y, color = Name)) + geom_line()
```

Of course, this does not work, as my quadratic model does not take into account the fact that I want to have a fit for each x values. But I have no idea how to do that.

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you regress on `Temperature`?

Comment: Yes, there is. Of course, this is just given as a reproducible example. In real life, I have data as a function of position (y = f(x)) and measurements where made at several temperatures. I need to extrapolate y = f(x) at a temperature that was not measured.

Comment: Ben, there is some deeper issue here besides programming. Although you got the puzzle parts right, you put them in an unsuitable way. So to make it short: you "need to extrapolate y = f(x)", therefore your formula is `y~bs(x, degree = 2)` given the training data (df1-4). Then you predict given new data df5. The response from this is a new set of `y`.s which you can plot. (Unrelated note: bs(Temperature, degree = 2)  will be 0 if Temperature is 0 - which it is in df.5. You need to specify your model right.) If you cannot get closer to solution I can later post an possible answer.

Comment: Also (self promotion :-), consider this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241091/how-can-i-measure-the-wave/ if you are dealing with wavy functions.

Comment: I guess my model is not correctly specified. I think what I want is for each x to find a model to compute y = f(T). I wonder if there is a function for that or if I need to do a for loop manually

Comment: so you want four regression models, each for a time group T ?

Comment: No I want 101 (the length of x) models. E.g. for x = 0, y1 = 1 at T = 4, y2 = 1.2 at T = 3, y3 = 1.4 at T = 2, y4 = 1.8 at T = 1. I need to use the model to find y5 at T= 0. Then loop on all x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your comments, this could be what you want:

```
#library(tidyverse)
df.merged %>%
  nest(-x) %>%
  mutate(Temperature = 0,
         model = map(data, lm, formula = y ~ bs(Temperature, degree = 2)),
         pred  = map_dbl(model, predict, newdata = data_frame(Temperature = 0))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = pred, color = factor(Temperature))) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = df.merged, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image: Cuuurves]

(If you need to un`dply` the code, just tell ;-))
**Edit: undypled version**

```
###
# WARNING: only works if data is ordered by x
###
# first split data into groupy by x
groupedData <- split(df.merged, x)
# for each group compute linear model
models <- lapply(groupedData, lm, formula = y ~ bs(Temperature, degree = 2))
# for each model make prediction for Temperature = 0
predictions <- sapply(models, predict, newdata = data.frame(Temperature = 0))
preddf <- data.frame(x = x, y = predictions, Name = "df.5", Temperature = 0)

ggplot(data = rbind(df.merged, preddf), aes(x = x, y = y, color =     factor(Temperature))) +
  geom_point()
```

I hope I got your intensions right, otherwise I could use more schematic figures that explain what you want.